Genrating question-answer pair is too slow over domain specific PDF dataset
I'm developing a chatbot pipeline using my own data and local LLM (such as Llama3). LlamaIndex is the orchestration framework that I'm using. In the data ingestion setup, I added the embedding fine-tuning concept to make the answers more accurate. As the dataset is somehow big (over 15000 pages), the question-answering pair generations, using the "generate_qa_embedding_pairs" function on Llamaindex, take too long (more than 24 hours on g5.12xlarge AWS instance). Do you have any recommendations to expedite the process?
To reference, I used the same idea as this post, although I used local LLM (llama3) instead of OpenAI models.
Thanks all in advanced :)
